# Using functions as arguments in hibernate aggregation functions

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql

I would like to perform the following query in HQL:

```
select count(distinct year(foo.date)) from Foo foo
```

However, this results in the following exception:

> org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
>   expecting CLOSE, found '(' near line
>   1, column 27

It seems that hibernate does not allow using functions as arguments to its aggregation functions. Is there any way to get the required result?

Comment: I am still interested in knowing if this can be achieved in pure HQL only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select the whole date
2. Loop over the result and extract a new collection made of the year from each date

At first it sounds ineffective, but then it's just an additional O(n), and I guess N isn't that big.

Another way is to use a native SQL query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, for compatibility issues with third-party software, I was hoping to be able to do it in a single query. I wonder if it could be done.

Comment: use native SQL query (not HQL)

Answer (score 0):

With criteria API could use [sqlProjection](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Projections.html#sqlProjection%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20org.hibernate.type.Type[]%29):

```
String func = format("count(distinct year(%s_.date))", criteria.getAlias());
String alias = "dateCol";
session.createCriteria(Foo.class).setProjection(
    sqlProjection(
        format("%s as %s", func, alias),
            new String[] { alias }, 
            new Type[] { Hibernate.LONG }
         )
     )
 );
```

This should work. I have not tested it.

The only problem with the sql projection is that you have to know (i.e. repeat) the column name.

Comment: Thanks for indicating the possibility of using hibernate Projections. Will have to delve into them deeper!