# QueryDSL: expecting CLOSE, found '('

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

What's so wrong with the following QueryDSL code:

```
query.from(chat).where(
chat.datePosted.goe(startDate.atStartOfDay()).
and(chat.datePosted.lt(endDate.plusDays(1).atStartOfDay()))).    
groupBy(date(chat.datePosted)).
list(date(chat.datePosted), date(chat.datePosted).count());
```

that I get an exception like this:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found '(' near line 1, column 41 [select date(chat.datePosted), count(date(chat.datePosted))
from com.test.model.Chat chat
where chat.datePosted >= ?1 and chat.datePosted < ?2
group by date(chat.datePosted)]
```

?

I'm using Spring Boot 1.3.6 and QueryDSL 3.7.4 (JPA via Hibernate).

Comment: Seems related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984611/querydsl-jpa-dayofyear-dayofmonth-translation-to-hibernate) but I refuse to believe hibernate cannot parse such a simple query.

Comment: It looks like the issue is around endDate.plusDays(1).atStartOfDay() - maybe try calculating that first then passing in the value?

Comment: DATE is not a valid JPQL function. Any JPQL reference would tell you this

Comment: You might be right but I've tried also plain old "concat" supported by queryDSL itself (or StringExpression append for that matter) and that doesn't work either so the root cause is something else.

Comment: @JohnHarris no, that worked just fine in the end, see the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refuse as I may it looks like [using functions as arguments in hibernate aggregation functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092111/using-functions-as-arguments-in-hibernate-aggregation-functions) is prohibited, eg.: count(date(field)) doesn't work with Hibernate. What a bummer!

Simply removing any call to another function under count() did the trick in my case because the results are the same. Seems like a Hibernate implementation issue since Timo mentions on the related question that this works under EclipseLink.